# How to form a greedy argument in Dafny?

Tags: binary-tree, greedy, proof, dafny

I am trying to verify the following solution to this problem.
https://leetcode.com/problems/diameter-of-binary-tree/description/

```
function diameter(node: TreeNode | null): [number, number] {
  if(node == null) {
    return [-1,-1];
  }
  if(node.left == null && node.right == null) {
    return [0, 0];
  }
  let leftDiameter = diameter(node.left);
  let rightDiameter = diameter(node.right);
  let height = Math.max(leftDiameter[0],rightDiameter[0]) + 1;
  let dim = leftDiameter[0]+rightDiameter[0]+2;
  let maxDiameter = Math.max(leftDiameter[1], rightDiameter[1], dim);
  return [height, maxDiameter];
}

function diameterOfBinaryTree(root: TreeNode | null): number {
  return diameter(root)[1];
};
```

And I have verified the following in Dafny.

```
method diameter(root: Tree) returns (heightDim: (int, int))
    requires ChildrenAreSeparate(root)
    ensures root == Nil ==> heightDim == (-1, -1)
    ensures root != Nil && root.left == Nil && root.right == Nil ==> heightDim == (0, 0)
    ensures heightDim.0 == TreeHeight(root)
    ensures root != Nil ==> exists start: Tree, end: Tree, path: seq<Tree> :: isTreePath(path, start, end) && |path| - 1 == heightDim.1  && isValidPath(path, root) && injectiveSeq(path)
{
    if root == Nil {
        return (-1, -1);
    }
    if root.left == Nil && root.right == Nil {
        ghost var path := [root];
        assert isTreePath([root], root, root);
        return (0,0);
    }
    var leftDiameter := diameter(root.left);
    var rightDiameter := diameter(root.right);
    var height := max(leftDiameter.0, rightDiameter.0) + 1;
    var dim := leftDiameter.0 + rightDiameter.0 + 2;
    var maxDiameter := max(leftDiameter.1, max(rightDiameter.1, dim));

    if root.right != Nil && root.left != Nil {
        BothCases(root, root.left, root.right, leftDiameter.0, rightDiameter.0);
        var rstart: Tree, rend: Tree, rightPath: seq<Tree> :| isTreePath(rightPath, rstart, rend) && |rightPath| - 1 == rightDiameter.1;
        var lstart: Tree, lend: Tree, leftPath: seq<Tree> :| isTreePath(leftPath, lstart, lend) && |leftPath| - 1 == leftDiameter.1;
        var start, end, path :| isTreePath(path, start, end) && |path| == leftDiameter.0 + rightDiameter.0 + 3 && injectiveSeq(path);
        if leftDiameter.1 > max(rightDiameter.1, dim) {
            assert maxDiameter == leftDiameter.1;
        }else if rightDiameter.1 > dim {
            assert maxDiameter == rightDiameter.1;
        }else{
            assert dim >= rightDiameter.1;
            assert dim >= leftDiameter.1;
            assert |path| - 1 == dim;
            assert maxDiameter == dim;
        }
    } else if root.right != Nil {
        var rstart: Tree, rend: Tree, rightPath: seq<Tree> :| isTreePath(rightPath, rstart, rend) && |rightPath| - 1 == rightDiameter.1 && isValidPath(rightPath, root);
        TreeHeightToDescTreePath(root.right, rightDiameter.0);
        var rpath: seq<Tree>, end: Tree :| (end != Nil && end.left == Nil && end.right == Nil && end in TreeSet(root.right))  && isDescTreePath(rpath, root.right, end) && |rpath| == rightDiameter.0+1 && isValidPath(rpath, root.right) && injectiveSeq(rpath);
        assert isDescTreePath([root]+rpath, root, end);
        DescTreePathToPath([root]+rpath, root, end);
        assert |[root]+rpath| == rightDiameter.0+2;
        parentNotInTreeSet(root, root.right);
        assert injectiveSeq([root]+rpath);
        assert leftDiameter.0 == -1;
        assert leftDiameter.1 == -1;
        if leftDiameter.1 > max(rightDiameter.1, dim) {
            assert false;
        }else if rightDiameter.1 > dim {
            assert maxDiameter == rightDiameter.1;
        }else{
            assert dim >= rightDiameter.1;
            assert dim >= leftDiameter.1;
            calc {
                dim;
                leftDiameter.0 + rightDiameter.0 + 2;
                -1 + rightDiameter.0 + 2;
                rightDiameter.0 + 1;
            }
            assert maxDiameter == dim;
            assert |[root]+rpath| - 1 == dim;
        }
    } else if root.left != Nil {
        var lstart: Tree, lend: Tree, leftPath: seq<Tree> :| isTreePath(leftPath, lstart, lend) && |leftPath| - 1 == leftDiameter.1;
        TreeHeightToDescTreePath(root.left, leftDiameter.0);
        var lpath: seq<Tree>, end: Tree :| (end != Nil && end.left == Nil && end.right == Nil && end in TreeSet(root.left))  && isDescTreePath(lpath, root.left, end) && |lpath| == leftDiameter.0+1 && isValidPath(lpath, root.left) && injectiveSeq(lpath);
        assert isDescTreePath([root]+lpath, root, end);
        DescTreePathToPath([root]+lpath, root, end);
        parentNotInTreeSet(root, root.left);
        assert injectiveSeq([root]+lpath);
        assert dim == leftDiameter.0 + 1;
        assert rightDiameter.0 == -1;
        assert rightDiameter.1 == -1;
        assert leftDiameter.1 >= 0;
        if leftDiameter.1 > max(rightDiameter.1, dim) {
            assert maxDiameter == leftDiameter.1;
        }else if rightDiameter.1 > dim {
            assert false;
        }else{
            assert dim >= rightDiameter.1;
            assert dim >= leftDiameter.1;
            assert maxDiameter == dim;
        }
    }

    return (height, maxDiameter);
}

method diameterOfBinaryTree(root: Tree) returns (maxDiameter: int)
    requires ChildrenAreSeparate(root)
    ensures root != Nil ==> exists start: Tree, end: Tree, path: seq<Tree> :: isTreePath(path, start, end) && |path| - 1 == maxDiameter && isValidPath(path, root) && injectiveSeq(path)
{
    var result := diameter(root);
    maxDiameter := result.1;
}
```

The full code is [here](https://github.com/hath995/dafny/blob/main/leetcode/DiameterOfBinaryTree.min.dfy) because it is actually far too long to fit in this post. Anyway, I have show that a valid path exists and is returned, but the problem suggests that it is the largest such path.

Intuitively, if the diameter returns the largest such path then either that value is returned or the sum of the two paths is larger. However, how should I form that predicate in Dafny?

My first attempt was

```
ghost predicate largestPath(path: seq<Tree>, root: Tree) {
    forall start: Tree, end: Tree, paths: seq<Tree> :: injectiveSeq(paths) && isTreePath(paths, start, end) && isValidPath(paths, root) ==> |path| >= |paths|
}
```

However, it does even validate for the simplest possible path.

```
method TestLp(root:Tree) {
    assert largestPath([root], root);
}
```

How can I reformulate this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer for you because it looks extremely complex, but I would suggest that you try to prove your assertion to see where it fails exactly. Here is how to write the skeleton of such a proof.

```
method TestLp(root:Tree) {
    assert largestPath([root], root) by {
      forall start: Tree, end: Tree, paths: seq<Tree>
        ensures injectiveSeq(paths) && isTreePath(paths, start, end) && isValidPath(paths, root) ==> |[root]| >= |paths|
{
        if  injectiveSeq(paths) && isTreePath(paths, start, end) && isValidPath(paths, root) {
          assert |[root]| >= |paths|;
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did actually prove that eventually. However, I'm still not sure how to prove the various inductive cases.

Comment: Can you please refine your question to a smaller self-containing example of things you are stuck with? I might be able to help then